# How Can I optimize this RewriteEngine Code?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have server overload, server admin said that this issue is caused from htaccess file

This is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /here/
RewriteRule ^top/?$ index.php?mode=top [QSA]
RewriteRule ^top/video/?$ index.php?mode=top&cat=vids [QSA]
RewriteRule ^top/picture/?$ /index.php?mode=top&cat=pics [QSA]

RewriteRule ^random$ index.php?mode=random [QSA]
RewriteRule ^random/video/?$ index.php?mode=random&cat=vids [QSA]
RewriteRule ^random/picture/?$ index.php?mode=random&cat=pics [QSA]

RewriteRule ^new/?$ index.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^new/video/?$ index.php?mode=&cat=vids [QSA]
RewriteRule ^new/picture/?$ index.php?mode=&cat=pics [QSA]

RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)_(.*)$ item.php?cat=vids&id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^picture/([0-9]+)_(.*)$ item.php?cat=pics&id=$1 [QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /item.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would get you half-way there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /here/
RewriteRule ^(top|random|new)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(top|random|new)/(video|picture)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&cat=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(video|picture)/([0-9]+)_(.*)$ item.php?cat=$1&id=$2 [QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /item.php
```

This isn't going to give you the exact same results -- your `cat` will either be `video` or `picture`, not `vids` or `pics`, so you'll have to change your script for this to work.

If you can't make that work you can use this slightly simplified version of yours:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /here/
RewriteRule ^(top|random|new)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^top/video/?$ index.php?mode=top&cat=vids [QSA]
RewriteRule ^top/picture/?$ /index.php?mode=top&cat=pics [QSA]

RewriteRule ^random/video/?$ index.php?mode=random&cat=vids [QSA]
RewriteRule ^random/picture/?$ index.php?mode=random&cat=pics [QSA]

RewriteRule ^new/video/?$ index.php?mode=&cat=vids [QSA]
RewriteRule ^new/picture/?$ index.php?mode=&cat=pics [QSA]

RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)_(.*)$ item.php?cat=vids&id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^picture/([0-9]+)_(.*)$ item.php?cat=pics&id=$1 [QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /item.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the rewriterules, put the routing completely into PHP and handle the 404 therein-

Example:

```
RewriteBase /my_blog

RewriteCond /var/www/my_blog/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond /var/www/my_blog/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^router.php [PT]
```

In `router.php` do a `var_dump($_SERVER);` so you see what the requested URL was and with what you can deal with.